# Using Sendgrid API with Wordpress

Tags: php, angularjs, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm trying to use the Sendgrid API on Wordpress, but getting this error
when inspecting.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://sendgrid.api-docs.io' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://localhost2' is therefore not allowed access.
```

First I though was a service that requires HTTPS, so I setup https on my local MAMP server but still not working, then I tried multiple strategies, namely changing htaccess file, adding CORS header in the file but nothing really worked.

```
$http.post('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send',mail,{ headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer MY IDENTICATION',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }})
    .success(function(data){
        console.log('Error' + data);
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log('Error' + data);
    });
```

This is the angular function I used to post to the API.

Can anyone help me to explain what exactly the error means( or am I missing anything)

Comment: Same issue like: https://github.com/sendgrid/docs/issues/1417

Answer (score 0):

I do not know Angular, so I might not fully understand the architecture. It looks to me like you are trying to make the API call from the client's browser. But, per Sendgrid's docs:

> When you have a browser-only application that reaches out to APIs, the
>   API key has to be embedded in the application. Anyone with access to a
>   browser-only application can access all of the Javascript source code,
>   including your API keys.
>
> Making your API key publicly accessible could result in anyone
>   authenticating API calls with your API key — this is a significant
>   security concern both for you and SendGrid.

via [SendGrid](https://sendgrid.com/docs/Classroom/Basics/API/cors.html)

Rather than making the API call from the browser on the front-end, be sure the call is being made from the back-end application itself.

Answer (score 0):

You run into the cross origin policy of the browser - sendgrid does not only allow accessing their API from other domains accept sendgrid.com itself. You can bypass this limitation using a middleware or proxy.

I wrote a tiny HTTP proxy for one of my Angular projects that can be hosted on Heroku using your credentials and one click deployment:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/sendgrid-proxy

Answer (score 0):

**sendGrid** CORS policy does not allow browsers to call their API (except if your are on "sendgrid.api-docs.io" domain) ... You have to send email from your server,

but if just for test or development purpose you can use my demo on github
https://github.com/itisnajim/sendgrid-nodejs

post your data to
http://sendgrid-nodejs-oxailstudiosnode.7e14.starter-us-west-2.openshiftapps.com